# How do I properly iterate through two separate files of unequal length in bash?

Tags: bash

I am relatively new to bash scripting.

I am attempting to create a bash script that will generate a list of SQL statements; I have a list of 'available hosts' & 'jobs' which I am pointing the script to (THE FILES ARE NOT THE SAME LENGTH).

```
$ cat avail_hosts.log
computer1
computer2
computer3
computer4
computer5

$ cat archiv_jobs.log
job1
job2
job3
job4
job5
```

The desired result of the script is to output a list of SQL statements that each contain a (unique) job and a (unique) host (see desired result below). For clarification, all jobs from 'archiv_jobs.log' must be assigned to a host; a single job should not be assigned to more than 1 host & a single host should not have more than 1 job assigned; any left-over hosts in 'avail_hosts.log' can be ignored after all jobs in 'archiv_jobs.log' are assigned. Lastly, there will never be an issue of more jobs than available hosts.

Currently, I am unable to make the script increment the host value so that it matches the 'desired output' below:

```
#! /bin/bash

rm ~/logs/assign_hosts.sql

sql_script=~/logs/assign_hosts.sql
host=~/logs/avail_hosts.log

for n in $(cat ~/logs/archiv_jobs.log)
do
    for h in $(cat ~/logs/avail_hosts.log)
    do
    host=$h
    done    
    printf "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = $host WHERE job_name='$n';\n" >> $sql_script
done
```

Current output: (same host)

```
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer1 WHERE job_name='Job1';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer1 WHERE job_name='Job2';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer1 WHERE job_name='job3....
```

Desired output: (unique host)

```
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer1 WHERE job_name='Job1';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer2 WHERE job_name='Job2';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer3 WHERE job_name='job3....
```

I have attempted to add ((h++)) to no avail:

```
for n in $(cat ~/logs/archiv_jobs.log)
do
    for h in $(cat ~/logs/avail_hosts.log)
    do
    host=$h
    ((h++))
    done    
    printf "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = $host WHERE job_name='$n';\n" >> $sql_script
done
```

Thank you to everyone that contributed & gave feedback! This was a case of beginner logic fail

SOLUTION: (courtesy of @merof)

```
i=0
for host in $(cat avail_hosts.log)
do
  n=$(sed -n "$((i+1))p" archiv_jobs.log | sed 's/ *$//')

  # If there are no more jobs, break out of the loop
  if [ -z "$n" ]; then
      break
  fi
  printf "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = $host WHERE job_name='$n';\n" >> str.tql
  ((i++))
done

Detailed explanation in comments section
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: hint: better `while read -r n; do ... done < ~/logs/archiv_jobs.log)` and the same for `h` also post ~10 lines of each of the input files.

Comment: please update the question to show a more representative set of inputs (you've mentioned in a separate comment that the 2 input files may not have the same number of lines/entries); perhaps remove `job5` from the 2nd file and then update the 2 sets of output to show the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output, making sure both sets of output correspond to the sample inputs

Comment: while you've added the following to the latest edit - *`any left-over hosts can be ignored.`* - you haven't updated the sample inputs to demonstrate this, nor have the two sets of output been updated; also, is it possible to have a leftover job?

Comment: `for n in $(cat ...)` doesn't work in general.  See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: `((h++)) ` does not make sense, becaues `h`  is already assigned in the `for` statement and most likely does not even hold a numeric value (unless the file `avail_hosts.log` contains only numbers). For a counter, initialize a variable of  different name **before** starting the loop, and increment it in the loop body. This is nothing specific to bash, but a generell idiom in programming.

Comment: Please format your code properly. The code below _SOLUTION_  and _If there are ..._ is virtually unreadable due to poor formatting.

Comment: format fixed - thanks for the tips & feedback!

Answer (score 5):

Assumptions:

- we want to match lines from the input files based on the line number
- per OP's latest description update (*`any left-over hosts can be ignored`*), we'll halt processing if we find we're missing a job

To demonstrate processing when there's an extra host (or job) we'll use the following inputs:

```
$ head avail_hosts.log archiv_jobs.log

==> avail_hosts.log <==
computer1
computer2
computer3
computer4                         # no matching entry from archiv_jobs.log

==> archiv_jobs.log <==
job1
job2
job3
```

While it's possible to write a `bash` shell script to step through both input files at the same time, I think we can simplify the code by first making use of `paste` to match the lines for us, eg:

```
$ paste avail_hosts.log archiv_jobs.log
computer1       job1
computer2       job2
computer3       job3
computer4                         # a leftover will show up as a single entry in the line
```

We can then feed this to a single `while/read` loop, eg:

```
while read -r host job            # if there's a leftover then the second variable (job) will be empty
do
    [[ -z "${job}" ]] && break    # if $job is empty then break out of loop (ie, halt generation of UPDATE statements)

    printf "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = '${host}' WHERE job_name='${job}';\n" > $sql_script

done < <(paste avail_hosts.log archiv_jobs.log)

###########
# or, to reduce the number of times we need to open/close $sql_script
# we can move the write operator to the end of the while loop:

while read -r host job
do
    [[ -z "${job}" ]] && break
    printf "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = '${host}' WHERE job_name='${job}';\n"

done < <(paste avail_hosts.log archiv_jobs.log) > $sql_script
```

This generates:

```
$ cat $sql_script
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = 'computer1' WHERE job_name='job1';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = 'computer2' WHERE job_name='job2';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = 'computer3' WHERE job_name='job3';
```

**NOTES:**

- this eliminates the need for this line from the current script: `host=~/logs/avail_hosts.log`
- I've gone ahead and wrapped the `$host` value in quotes (in the `UPDATE` statement) since I'm assuming the `host_name` column's datatype is a string/(var)char
- if OP prefers to read from both files at the same time I'd suggest a web search on `bash read two files concurrently site:stackoverflow.com` (brings up many Q&As that address this approach)

Comment: The two files DO NOT have the same amount of lines unfortunately - would you know how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: @RyanAcevedo please update the question to demonstrate what we're supposed to do in that situation; for example, if we have an 'extra' host (or job), do we discard the extra? do we re-use the previous value for the 'missing' item? you need to tell us what to do with the host (or job) that does not have a matching job (or host); also confirm if we're supposed to match the entries from the two files simply based on line number, or is there some substring (within the host/job strings) that we're supposed to be matching on?

Comment: post updated & solution provided - thanks for your time, paste will be a great option in the future!

Comment: @RyanAcevedo fwiw, `paste` can still be used when inputs don't have same number of lines  ... instead of 2 values read by the `while/read` only one value is read (ie, 2nd variable is left empty), so just test 2nd variable for emptiness (`-z "${job}"`)

Comment: Just used this to write a new script - worked like a charm, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `awk`?

```bash
awk 'NR==FNR {a[++n]=$0; next} {print "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = " a[++o] " WHERE job_name=\x27" $0 "\x27;"}' file1 file2
```

Above, `awk` makes a pass through `file1` and fills the array `a[]`, sequentially indexed, with the `file1` contents. `FNR == NR` simply tests if the current file record equals the total number of records process (e.g. in 1st file). Then when reading the `file2`, the corresponding array element is output, in-place in the query with the content of `file2` placed between single-quotes (e.g. `\x27`) at the end.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[++n]=$0; next} {print "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = " a[++o] " WHERE job_name=\x27" $0 "\x27;"}' avail_hosts.log activ_jobs.log
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer1 WHERE job_name='job1';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer2 WHERE job_name='job2';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer3 WHERE job_name='job3';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer4 WHERE job_name='job4';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer5 WHERE job_name='job5';
```

Answer (score 1):

Great!
You have the basic structure but missing a few things

I think you meant to do `printf` in the nested for loop, not in the other one
change

```bash
    done
    printf "UPDATE...
done
```

to

```bash
    printf "UPDATE...
    done
done
```

Then, what is `$h`? if you do `echo $h` it will write a host name.

```
╰─ bash testing.sh
hostA
...
```

if you do a ++ operator on a string, host name, you do get it working, but it will give you a number, 1 in this case

```bash
#loops
((h++))
echo $h
```

```
 bash testing.sh
1
1
```

### Answer

Now then
now you should have it like this and working

```bash
...
for h in $(cat avail_hosts.log)
    do
      host=$h
      printf "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = $host WHERE job_name='$n';\n" >> str.tql
done
```

and well you can remove `host=$h` and just use `$h` or do
`for host in $(cat avail_hosts.log)`

`str.tql` for me

```
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = hostA WHERE job_name='job1';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = hostB WHERE job_name='job1';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = hostC WHERE job_name='job1';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = hostA WHERE job_name='job2';
...
```

**Additional info**: one job per server
For that, we assume that we don't care about job count
And remove inner loop.
And change main loop to iterate hosts not jobs, although you can reverse it easily
Now we also need to have a iterator for jobs, we will add `i`

```bash
i=1
for host in $(cat avail_hosts.log)
do
  n=$(sed -n "$((i+1))p" archiv_jobs.log)

  # If there are no more jobs, break out of the loop
  if [ -z "$n" ]; then
      break
  fi
  printf "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = $host WHERE job_name='$n';\n" >> str.tql
  ((i++))
done
```

`i=1` because files
`if [ -z "$n" ]; then` checks if there's no more jobs
`n=$(sed -n "$((i))p" archiv_jobs.log)` gets the current job
`((i++))` increment

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! However, this will not work for me as I only want 1 (unique) job assigned to 1 (unique) host

In other words, each job must be assigned to a unique host as such:

UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer1 WHERE job_name='Job1';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer2 WHERE job_name='Job2';
UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = computer3 WHERE job_name='job3....

Comment: You have to write that in your question.
So jobs don't repeat, right? Easy.
But for that you have to give even more info. 

If there are more jobs than servers, what to do? 
I will update answer

Comment: worked beautifully, but I get a huge chunk of white space at the end of the SQL statement: UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = eagnmnmep16ec WHERE job_name='trpCarrierRoutesDetailArchival                                                  ';

Comment: could you elaborate on this line?  n=$(sed -n "$((i+1))p" archiv_jobs.log) - how can I fix the trailing white space?

Comment: nvm I got it - I had to trim the trailing space with 's/ *$//' - so I just updated the script to n=$(sed -n "$((i+1))p" archiv_jobs.log | 's/ *$//')

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would not be a problem. At this point it's indeed better to just remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash (version 4.0+) code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

readarray -t hosts <avail_hosts.log
readarray -t jobs  <archiv_jobs.log

for ((i=0; i<${#jobs[*]}; i++)); do
    printf "UPDATE %s SET host_name = %s WHERE job_name='%s';\\n"   \
        'pw_batch_app.job_control' "${hosts[i]}" "${jobs[i]}"
done >assign_hosts.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra integer variable `i` that you increment:

```
#! /bin/bash

rm ~/logs/assign_hosts.sql
sql_script=~/logs/assign_hosts.sql
host=~/logs/avail_hosts.log

i=0
for n in $(cat ~/logs/archiv_jobs.log) ; do
    for h in $(cat ~/logs/avail_hosts.log) ; do
        host=$h
    done    
    i=$((i+1))
    host="$host$i"
    printf "UPDATE pw_batch_app.job_control SET host_name = $host WHERE job_name='$n';\n" >> $sql_script
done
```

Note that the logic of this script escapes me completely, so the `i=0` and the increment may be at the wrong place. For example: why do

```
    for h in $(cat ~/logs/avail_hosts.log) ; do
        host=$h
    done
```

instead of

```
    host=$(tail -1 ~/logs/avail_hosts.log)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Like I mentioned in the post, I am new to bash scripting so the logic may very well be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an old version of Bash (pre-4.0), or you want to be able to use the code with other shells, try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean POSIX shell code:

```
#! /bin/sh -

while { read -r j || [ -n "$j" ]; } && { read -r h <&3 || [ -n "$h" ]; }; do
    printf "UPDATE %s SET host_name = %s WHERE job_name='%s';\\n"   \
        'pw_batch_app.job_control' "$h" "$j"
done <archiv_jobs.log 3<avail_hosts.log >assign_hosts.sql
```

- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of the shell features used in the code.